# Pycharm Type Hint Error not showing for class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Pycharm is only showing type error at self.b:int = "abc". But its not showing error at a: int = "abc", Nor its showing error at t1.b = "def". Anyone knows why?

In all cases, it should have shown error because the code is trying to assign string value to variable thats declared as int. I even installed MyPy plugin to see if that helps. But it did not.

```
class TestClass:
    a: int = "abc"

    def __init__(self):
        self.b: int = "abc"


t1 = TestClass()
t1.b = "def"
```

Comment: This could be considered a bug, but if you want `a` to be treated as a class attribute, use `a: typing.ClassVar[int] = ...` instead of `a: int = ...`

Comment: (`mypy` flags the assignment to `a` as an error regardless. I wonder if Pycharm only considers the type hint to apply to an instance attribute `a`, and considers `TestClass.a` to have type `Any`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two known PyCharm issues, see

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41113/No-warning-for-wrong-type-in-instance-attribute
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36889/Check-type-in-class-attribute-assignments-Incompatible-types-in-assignment